# using soaplib to connect to remote SOAP server lacking definition

Tags: python, soap, introspection

I am looking at the soaplib python module (it comes with standard ubuntu 9.04).  I have used xmlrpclib extensively in the last years but now I am curious about soap.  writing servers with soaplib is acceptably easy, I assume writing clients should be even easier.

in my impatience I can't find a way to make use of introspection.  do I really need to describe each and every method in the server in order to define the client ( http://trac.optio.webfactional.com/wiki/Client )?

I find this difficult to believe, but I can't find any significant web page holding my three search terms: python soap introspect...

so the question sounds: can I use Python soaplib to access just any remote web service of which I only know the URL?  and how do I do that?

am I or is the library missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to generate client code for a given webservice without defining what methods etc are availible on that service in your own code directly?  IE: you would like to introspect the service and generate client automatically.

If this is the case then the answer is that you need to use the [soaplib trunk](http://github.com/jkp/soaplib/tree/master).  Specifically you will be interested in a [recently contributed script](http://github.com/jkp/soaplib/blob/f61ddf293c67d6e3a95fa9d75c6e354e38969b52/soaplib/ext/wsdl2py.py) that allows the generation of Python classes to act as a client to a given service as described in a [WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) file.  There are scripts in soaplib to allow the generation of classes both in a static manner (where a .py module is generated and written to disk) and in a dynamic manner where the classes exist only at runtime in your program.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes, that is the situation.  it's not an urgent thing and it is temporarily parked.  the scripts you point to, do they only work with the soaplib bleeding edge?

Comment: Yeah, thats correct: watch this space because there is some work going on with those scripts right now to make them interoperate better with more complex services.